Как дать доступ декомпилированному приложению к /dev/fm?
Всех приветствую. Имеем оригинал приложения фм радио и его декомпилированную версию. Декомпилированная версия не хочет проигрывать радио. Как мне подсказали,мы можем давать доступ приложениям к драйверам устройств через setenforce 0,но это значение слетает после перезагрузки смарта и этот вариант небезопасен,т.к тогда доступ ко всем драйверам смогут получить все приложения,кому не лень,просто с этим режимом работает даже декомпилированная версия,т.е подписанная моим ключом,а не ключом прошивки (когда я переподписывал оригинал моим ключом,радио тоже не будет играть,пока я не выполню команду setenforce 0). Можно ли как-то предоставить доступ к драйверам конкретному приложению навсегда,если у меня есть рут? Мне уже подсказывали,что надо написать какое-то правило для selinux. Также мне подсказали,что можно переподписать прошивку прямо на моём смарте,т.к apk,подписанный оригинальным ключом,всегда имеет доступ к /dev/fm,но я нашёл старый мануал,который не факт,что заработает.
Мой смарт agm m7 с api 27 и прошивкой LineageOS. На нём есть рут и magisk. Если у вас есть идеи,помогите мне пожалуйста. Вы можете также писать мне в личку,или в телегу (t.me/sashablr_1994). Заранее благодарю всех за помощь.
